# How to directly query the camera about image luminance/ Skip compentation in OpenCV

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, opencv

I am developing a program in VS 2010 using OpenCV. I want to measure the luminance of every frame that the computer's camera  captures. However, the camera's software stabilizes the luminance after 2-3 frames. Eg, if i put my thumb in front of the camera the first frame's luminance is 2 (scale from 0 to 255), but then while keeping my thumb in front of the camera the luminance becomes 7 and the 20 - it is stabilized there for the next frames. So the camera tries to make too dark pictures brighter and too bright pictures darker.

How can i measure the actual luminance without the camera's interference?
My code is:

```
#ifdef _CH_
#pragma package <opencv>
#endif
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <highgui.h>

#include "cv.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "..\utilities.h"

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
FILE *file;
IplImage *img;
IplImage* grayscale_image;
int c, i, j, Luminance = 0, Pixel_Num = 0;
int Avg_Luminance;
int width_step;
int pixel_step;
// allocate memory for an image

// capture from video device #1
CvCapture* capture;
// create a window to display the images
cvNamedWindow("mainWin", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
// position the window
cvMoveWindow("mainWin", 5, 5);
while(1)
{
    if(file = fopen("luminance_value.txt", "w+"))
    {
        // retrieve the captured frame
        capture= cvCaptureFromCAM(1);
        img=cvQueryFrame(capture);

        grayscale_image = cvCreateImage( cvGetSize(img), 8, 1 );
        cvConvertImage( img, grayscale_image );
        width_step= grayscale_image->widthStep;
        pixel_step= grayscale_image->widthStep/grayscale_image->width;
        Pixel_Num = grayscale_image->width * grayscale_image->height;
        for(i = 0; i < grayscale_image->height; i++)
        {
            for(j = 0; j < grayscale_image->width; j++)
            {
                unsigned char* point = GETPIXELPTRMACRO( grayscale_image, j, i, width_step, pixel_step);
                Luminance += point[0];
            }
        }
        Avg_Luminance = Luminance / Pixel_Num;
        //Avg_Luminance = cvGetCaptureProperty(capture,CV_CAP_PROP_BRIGHTNESS);
        //file = fopen("luminance_value.txt", "w+");
        fprintf(file, "%d", Avg_Luminance);
        fclose(file);
        printf("Avg_Luminance = %d\n", Avg_Luminance);
        Luminance = 0;
        Pixel_Num = 0;
        // show the image in the window
        cvShowImage("mainWin", grayscale_image );
        cvReleaseCapture(&capture);
        // wait 10 ms for a key to be pressed
        c=cvWaitKey(10000);
        // escape key terminates program
        if(c == 27)
        break;
    }
    else
    {
        continue;
    }

    }
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: You might look at [`cvSetCaptureProperty()`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#videocapture-set) with the argument `CV_CAP_PROP_EXPOSURE`.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but actually it didn't work. What i did actually was to connect an arduino with a photo-resistor to my computer, in order to measure the actual luminance in the room. Then , the value of the luminance was send through the serial port to the VS Server. It would be nice if anyone would post a solution to this problem by using his camera.